# determining if an array list beginning and ending and displaying everything in between

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to filter through an array list that contains the content of a URL that is stored in: `(List<String> quotes = new ArrayList<>();)` and, display the result for every thing that is in between `<pre> </pre>` tags (all the quotes are placed between these two tags). I already figured out the printing part but is there any method in java that allows you to filter an array list as I specified? thanks

more detail:

So you have your normal html file that contains all kinds of tags. lets say I scan the page and store all the text in a string array. I want to display only the content between `<pre></pre>` tags and not the rest. Hope this helps

here is how the text is stored:

```
List<String> cookies = new ArrayList<>();    
public void init() throws ServletException 
    {
        try 
        {
         URL url = new URL(" http://fortunes.cat-v.org/openbsd/");
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
         String line ;

           while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
           {
          cookies.add(line);
          //line = in.readLine();
           }
         in.close(); 
     }

    catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) 
    {
      System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
      System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, at least to me. Can you provide an example of what this list may contain and what you want to print?

Comment: So you have your normal html file that contains all kinds of tags. lets say I scan the page and store all the text in a string array. I want to display only the content between <pre></pre> tags and not the rest. Hope this helps

Comment: It doesn't really help. You need to tell us how the html is stored in the `ArrayList`. It could be line by line or only `String`s of length 1 or something else. Also include this info in the question, don't just post a comment, since it's easier to find there and not all users are willing to read through all the comments.

Comment: I added some code, hope this clears it up,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use regular expression, here's a full working example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;




public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        //This list is supposed filled with some values
        List<String> quotes = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String quote:quotes){
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?<pre>(.*?)</pre>.*?");
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(quote);
            while(m.find()){
                String result = m.group(1);
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        }


}
```

}

Comment: thanks for the answer how can I specify say if the quotes were stored between % signs? like so:  %quote 1%quote 2%quote 3%quote 4%quote 5%quote ...%

Comment: if you mean the % sign will replace the <pre>, then just use the same code and replace it in the regular expression: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?%(.*?)%.*?");

Comment: the % are between the <pre> tags like so : <pre> %quote 1%quote 2%quote 3%quote 4%quote 5%quote ...%</pre>

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the String "pre" and index of "/pre" and loop for all the elements between

```
int startIndex=quotes.IndexOf("<pre>");
int endIndex=c.IndexOf("</pre>");

for(int i=startIndex ; i<=endIndex ; i++){
  // do something here ... 
  // System.out.println(quotes.get(i));
}
```